How do I disable this type of notification in Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022?

I do not know the name for this 'feature' that creates these notifications, but I want to disable it entirely in MS Visual Studio Professional 2022 Version 17.10.3
The VS project is generated/modified by the Unity3D Editor, and these notifications sometimes spam non-stop while the Unity editor is processing. The notifications appear as a banner between my open document tabs, and the toolbar at the top of the VS window.

It's not a feature, it's actually reporting an error, have you investigated the source of the internal error? What version of VS2022 this sounds like a bug with VS itself

It's an error that I do not care about in the least, but it very annoyingly shifts all my tabs down when it displays. It is purely because the solution linking got messed up / modified by the Unity editor and the editor is churning while processing something (loading a many assets / recompiling code/shaders / ect..)
It will get fixed after Unity finishes it's tasks but in the mean time I can continue working on the code and would prefer not having my windows suddenly shift up/down as useless notifications appear.
I stated the version 17.10.3

Sorry, I was busy typing the error message, instead of copying the error message

I had this issue and I eventually figured out it was caused by adding <inheritdoc cref="..."/> XML documentation to multiple overloaded C# methods with generic type parameters. I eventually gave up and manually copied the documentation to each overloaded method, which fixed these crashes.
